# Undo invalid error due to the group by clause

Tags: asp.net, sql, error-handling, group-by

Having an error with the code... Staff.StaffId/Name always gets pointed out as an error.
Want to select staffID, anem and years in service with the conditions that supervisor ID=7 and 'years in service' < 10

```
Column 'Staff.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.


select staffId,Name, DATEDIFF(year,DateJoin,GETDATE()) as 'Years in Service' from Staff
JOIN Branch ON Branch.BranchNo=Staff.BranchNo
where SupervisorID=7 
having COUNT(*) <10
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to simply add a Group By clause to the function. Try:

```
select staffId,Name, DATEDIFF(year,DateJoin,GETDATE()) as 'Years in Service' from Staff
JOIN Branch ON Branch.BranchNo=Staff.BranchNo
where SupervisorID=7
GROUP BY staff.name, staff.staffId
having COUNT(*) <10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `group by` clause if you have a `count()` and want more than one row:

```
select staffId,Name, DATEDIFF(year, DateJoin, GETDATE()) as [Years in Service]
from Staff JOIN
     Branch
     ON Branch.BranchNo = Staff.BranchNo
where SupervisorID = 7 
group by staffId, Name
having COUNT(*) < 10;
```

In addition, you should not use single quotes for column names.  Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants.  Also, it is a good idea to use table aliases to identify where each column is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should be using `HAVING` - an "`AND`" will do ....

```
select staffId,Name, DATEDIFF(year,DateJoin,GETDATE()) as 'Years in Service' from Staff
JOIN Branch ON Branch.BranchNo=Staff.BranchNo
where SupervisorID=7 
and DATEDIFF(year,DateJoin,GETDATE()) <10
```